# pick color from css gradient for coloring text

Tags: html, css, colors, gradient

I have a colorgradient created in css. At the moment the text is black but I want to color the scale according to the matching color in the gradient.

[image]

Of course I can type it in manually but how can I do this in a more automatic way.

```css
 .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-top: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#grad1 {
  height: 55px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #d91918, #f8542f, #ee77aa, #ffcd46);
}
```

```html
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="grad1">
  <div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: So you want "1" to have a yellowish color and "10" a reddish color. Am I correct?

Comment: exactly. and the rest in between :)

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with some modifications to your code, I have achieved the desired effect-

1. Separated the `#grad1` and `.container`. (You can wrap then in a div for convenience)
2. Give the same background to `.container`.
3. Use two properties `-webkit-background-clip` and `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` to do the magic.

The `-webkit-background-clip` holds the background only to the text. But we can't see it because the text is not transparent. To override the default `color` property and make the text transparent, we use `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent`.

```css
.container {
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #d91918, #f8542f, #ee77aa, #ffcd46);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
}

#grad1 {
  height: 55px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #d91918, #f8542f, #ee77aa, #ffcd46);
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

**Note** - This trick works only in `webkit` browsers and things might break on non-webkit browsers. To prevent this, provide a fallback color property to the text.